# TV Episode with Frankenstein-like creature

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror, hard-sci-fi

I remember watching a TV show when I was younger -- I was born in '77, so I am guessing it was in the mid-80's -- where a scientist/doctor put together a small creature using spare body parts.

The creature was whitish and there was a scene where the camera was focused in on the creature's feet as it walked down the stairs (I remember this distinctly because something about the way the creature walked scared the crap out of me).

I had always thought that it was an episode of Tales from the Darkside but I just looked at an episode list and none of the synopses seemed to fit.

Comment: There are many TV series from that area which would fit. Twilight Zone, Tales From The Crypt, The Outer Limits etc.

Comment: Could it have been from the Monsters TV series?  That was late 1980s.

Comment: @DarenW Ah yes. One of the few that wasn't a revival of an earlier series! The others were better though.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a bit like the Tales From the DarkSide episode "Inside the Closet": http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0716953/?ref_=tt_ep_ep7

Basic story: a young grad student rents a room from an anthropologist who seems to be hiding some creature in a closet. The white, hairless, ape-like creature (made by Tom Savini) is what makes me think of this ep in particular. There are some close-up shots focusing on the puppet's feet as it walks down the stairs, exactly like you described. There isn't any mention of the scientist creating the creature himself, but the twist is that he loves it and treats it as his child (hugging it, telling it that it's pretty, taking it upstairs to tuck it in and read it a story).

You can watch it here and see if it's what you're looking for:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

There was a TV show called "Small Wonder."  But it wasn't scary - it was a comedy.  The father was an engineer and he created a robot girl and tried to pass her off as human, leading to many comical situations. This gave them free labor as she was basically a robot slave.