# TV Movie or Series Episode Featuring Diminutive Female Monster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, tv, horror

I think this aired on network television in the mid to late 1980s. It's either a TV movie or an episode from an anthology series. I believe the protagonist is a woman who's either inherited or is staying in a spooky mansion. During her stay she experiences strange occurrences that lead her to the discovery of a small closet filled with little girl's dresses and toys. Later she encounters a small creature that kills her. It's suggested that this creature is a deformed child to whom the things in the closet belongs. I recall reading about this show in TV Guide and seeing a photo of the creature being held by an old man in a magazine. My sister watched this program and told me about it. I always wanted to see it, but never got the opportunity. I'd love it if someone could help me find out the title and more information on this.

Comment: Can you describe that small creature? Height, face, arms, possible claws, etc? Who was that older man? Describe him also.

Comment: Chucky/Child's play?

Comment: I recall the creature somewhat resembling the Rancor from Return of the Jedi. As for the older man, I really can't remember any details.

Answer (score 7):

I found it! It's an episode of [*Tales from the Darkside*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0086814/) titled "[Inside the Closet](https://imdb.com/title/tt0716953/?ref_=m_ttep_ep_ep8)"! (Season 1, episode 7)

Quoting the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tales_from_the_Darkside_episodes) on Wikipedia:

> Graduate student Gail Aynsley (Roberta Weiss) takes up a room for rent in the house of Dr. Fenner (Fritz Weaver), the dean of a local veterinary school. She discovers that her new room has a strange miniature door inside it, and estimates that there may be something lurking on the other side.

Comment: Congrats! Don't forget to click on the checkmark to self-accept. You won't be able to do so until 48 hours after asking the question, but it will let you know how muchy time is left if you click early.

Comment: It looks like https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37801/tv-episode-with-frankenstein-like-creature/50965#50965 also provided this as an answer, but it was not accepted, so there's no dupe involved. :) Just mentioning it so that the system provides links between them.